# Can I downgrade swift version to moderate error 'Module compiled with Swift x.x cannot be imported by the Swift x.x compiler'?

Tags: ios, swift

I recently started my very first swift experience and I got an error

> 'Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0
>   compiler'

I thought that I can moderate this error just selecting my swift language version on build settings. but it doesn't work.

[image]

After few searching, I found that there are two options

1. Downgrade Xcode
2. Update modules or Rebuild modules using swift 5.0

Are they only options I got? I don't know why changing swift language version does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swift 5 compiler which is bundled with Xcode 10.2 can compile in swift 4 mode. However, it is still the swift 5 compiler and not the swift 4 compiler that came in Xcode 10.1. Modules built with the swift 4 compiler can’t be imported by the swift 5 compiler.

Therefore, the two options you listed are the only options you have.

Comment: Yup. The following link gives you more details. Module stability (which you want) might come in Swift 6. https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/

Comment: I ended up with downgrading my xcode.  but anyway thank you for your nice and precise explanation.